# path.reset with menu item onclick

Tags: android, view, reset

I'm making an paint application just to learn how to work with eclipse.

I would like to clear my (paint)view whenever I click the menu item 'Reset'
The menu item 'Reset' is in the XML file. Now i know i have to use path.reset but don't know how where to write it. Hope someone is able to help me out.

```
 <item android:id="@+id/ResetAction"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Reset"
        android:showAsAction="never" 
        android:menuCategory="container"
        ></item>
```

a

```
public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity 

{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Path.reset() is a method used to reuse a Path object.

For example, if you use a Path object to draw a shape that changes at each frame, at the beginning of the frame drawing (in the draw(Canvas) or onDraw(Canvas) methods) you can reset reset the path, add the new shape to the path and then draw the Path (canvas.drawPath())